# Modify the Genesis file/WASM after getting the slot but before the parachain creates the block

Tags: parachain, wasm, genesis, slot

I want to find a way to check whether the parachain's genesis file/WASM can be changed after getting the slot but before creating the first block by the users who registered the parachain. Is that possible?

I discovered that two extrinsic, forceSetcurrentCode and forceSetCurrentHead, can be used, but you have to send them by the sudo user, not the user who registered parachain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the calls you need.

You can only open a referendum on relaychain to update the genesis.

And I think this is reasonable.

Because users bid/contribute for your parachain slot, you shouldn't casually change the genesis.